# new line into SELECT query sql server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to do a new line in my sql select

I try this but it won't work

```
SELECT '1' + char(13) + '2'
```

AND

```
SELECT '1' + char(13) + char(10) + '2'
```

it always return 12

thanks for your answers 
in fact I try to export data from sql to TXT file 
but when I execute the bcp file it return concatenate rows

Comment: It's not the it always returns 12, it's just that the results are seen like that on the grid of SQL Server Management Studio. Hint: try the same but choosing "Results to text"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new line is in your result.  If you copy and paste the result from your query into notepad, for example, you'll see 1, new line, 2. The reason you see `1  2` in your result in the results window is because you are returning 1 row. Notice that len('1' + char(13) + char(10) + '2') = 4, that is because your chars are present, it's just represented as a single row (with multiple lines in the row).

Comment: This is wrong. Copying to clipboard doesn't add any new lines. Dave Zych's answer is correct you need to choose Results to Text to be able to copy the new lines

Answer (score 1):

That's just the way SSMS displays the results. If you copy the result out into Notepad, or as Lamak says choose `Results to Text` you should see the newlines in place.